# Android WebView With Reader Mode

Tags: android, webview

i just wanna know can we use chromium features in our Android WebView ? i am curious can we add chromium reader mode features on the WebView when we load some url in webview like pocket, readability or instapaper, or there is some base knowladge to doing that?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525741/enabling-read-mode-support-in-android-webview

Comment: This duplicate reference is to a question which lists THIS question as a duplicate. That is...unhelpful.

Answer (score -1):

Previous to Android 4.4, it was possible to enable reader mode in `WebView` using [WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html#NARROW_COLUMNS) or [WebSettings.LayoutAlgoritym.SINGLE_COLUMN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html#SINGLE_COLUMN). However, when `WebView` was [rebased on the Blink engine in Android 4.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(web_engine)) to share the same code base as Chromium [these layout options were removed](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#Columns).