# Reader Mode for Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm looking for a way to open a URL in a web view in reader mode. Is this possible to do in a simple web view? I've looked and have found other questions about this but they have no answers.

Comment: What is "reader mode" with respect to a `WebView`?

Comment: It's an older article, but this is how I want to be able to display some of the URLs in my apps WebViews. http://lifehacker.com/enable-the-new-hidden-reader-mode-in-chrome-for-andro-1666469700

Comment: any thing find yet ? @raginggoat

Comment: I never found anything so I just gave up on it.

Comment: then how people useing in own apps?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pakdata.urdunews&hl=en

Comment: check this its using i think

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664338/android-webview-with-reader-mode/46060576

Comment: I searched but like you I didn't find anything easy to use, I'm pretty sure there is not such feature available for web:https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/ArticleViewer.java

which is about reader mode of Telegram and I know it's not easy to use it!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible, the [Webview API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)) has been created long before this feature existed and the API does not provide a way of activating arbitrary chrome features which are added to Chrome later.

You could however use [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs), and then app users could enable it themselves if Chrome decides to show the "Show simplifed view" popup.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I finally ended using the following library to display my news articles in my android app

You can check this out,

[Reader-Mode-Gouse-Mohiddin-Android-Link-Preview-Library](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview)

Comment: So nice! Why don't you continue to develop it?