# Enabling Read Mode Support in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

Is there any way to enable read mode in android WebView? I know it is supported by SFSafariViewController in IOS but couldn't find whether it's supported by Android WebView or not.

Thx!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664338/android-webview-with-reader-mode/46060576