# How to set reader mode in Android WebView ?

Tags: android, webview

I am searching for it since long time but I haven't got proper solution.

Used [this link](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Chrome-for-Android-How-to-enable-mobile-friendly-Reader-mode-for-any-web-site_id84066) to set reader mode in chrome.

But I am not getting any idea or code example to set reader mode in Android WebView.

Comment: I think that there is no such thing in `WebView`. Maybe you could try using https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664338/android-webview-with-reader-mode/46060576.

Comment: Did you got the solution?